# Back button goes to the parent activity instead going to the phone home screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have two activities, A y B. A is the parent activity of B.

A initialise the second one with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, B.class );
startActivity( intent );
this.finish();
```

and the B goes back to A (like a logout) with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( B.this, A.class );
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
startActivity( intent );
```

Giving you some more context, the app has a sliding menu and each list item shows a ListFragment within a ListView. On each of those views the back stack has been cleaned and the idea is when the user press onto the back button, he should go to the phone home screen as [Google documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) says and when the user press on the app icon from the phone home screen, it needs to re-init where the user was working on.

What the app is currently doing is going to the phone home screen, but when you press onto the app icon, it starts again from the activity A, which is the launch and main activity.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding after `startActivity()` `finish()`.
That will make the provius activity to safely close itself.

Comment: If I call this.finish(); on the activity A after the startActivity(this, B.class); when the user press onto the Back Button from any ListView, the app goes to the phone home screen, but when I press on the app icon, it starts on the activity A. Do you think I do need to change something on my AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, probably on your manifest, Activity A is parent of Activity B. Removing this will make it go back to home screen

Comment: I've done that, but the problem persist. After the app has gone to the phone home screen and I press onto the app icon, the app restarts from the activity A.

Answer (score 1):

You use this code to go to phone Home screen

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Override `onBackPressed` and write the above code. It should work.

Comment: I added those lines on the onBackPressed, and It goes to the phone home screen, but when I press onto the app icon, it starts on the activity A instead where the user was working.

Comment: That is how every application works. If you want to see the page from where the user has left, then you should open them from shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, You have 2 activities A & B.

You are starting Activity A & moving to Activity B same timing calling A.this.finish()

It means there is only 1 activity present in your stack which is Activity B.

And when you press "Back" button, it means its closing your app that removing remaining Activity B from stack, so your stack gets empty. So you need to press "Center" button of your device which will keep your app activity B in background (in onStop() state) & when you start your app again so it will open activity B only (by calling onRestart()).

I hope above explanation is highly sufficient to understand above problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and is totally what is happening. Is there any way to fix it? I mean, how to make the app save the state of activity B, even if the user goes to the phone home screen using the Back Button?

Comment: Actually there is no way to handle this. Because android is a stack-based operating system. So when you press back button, it just remove that activity from stack. Another thing is when you get correct answer you should upvote & accept that answer so other can follow that answer.

Comment: Best way to handle it is press center button not back button. Because android OS has been designed in that way only, so nobody can change it

Comment: I am talking about UX dude and what the user most use. Thanks for your help I am busy looking for a fix to this navigation issue.

Comment: Android may kill the Activity B (which is onStop mode) sometimes.